# Why isnt entropy change in free expansion = 0?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

$dS = \delta Q/T$

According to this equation, it seems as though for all adiabatic processes, the entropy change should be 0, since $\delta Q = 0$ always.

I know I'm wrong since for free expansion we use the property that S is a state function hence calculate the change in entropy based on final and initial P,V,T, which turns out to be a non zero value.

Why is the equation $dS = \delta Q/T$ seemingly invalid for free expansion/any irreversible adiabatic process? Am I interpreting this equation and its use case wrong?
(I guess this equation is only valid for reversible processes)

Comment: When you learned that "$dS=dQ/T$" was there *any* restriction perhaps on the type of process for when that equation was true? Check again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation applies only for reversible processes.  For both irreversible and reversible process of a closed system, the Clausius relation applies: $$\Delta S = \int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}+\sigma$$ where $\sigma$ represents the amount of entropy generated within the system during the process (positive definite) and $T_B$  is the temperature of the interface/boundary between the system and surroundings through which the heat exchange dQ takes place.

There are only two ways that the entropy of a closed system can change during a process:

(1) entropy transfer across the boundary of the system with its surrounds.  This mechanism is characteristic of both reversible and irreversible processes, and is given by $\int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}$.

(2) entropy generation within the system as a result of irreversibilities typically associated with transport processes:  viscous dissipation of mechanical energy at finite velocity gradients, internal heat conduction at finite temperature gradients, and internal molecular diffusion at finite concentration gradients.  This mechanism is characteristic of irreversible processes only.

Comment: Do you have any questions about my answer?

Answer (score 2):

> I guess this equation is only valid for reversible processes

Yes.

$dS=\delta Q/T$ is only valid for reversible processes. More precisely, it is valid for processes where the mechanical action (work) is reversible. The reversibility of heat exchange with the environment does not matter. The simplest way to see it is:

$$dU=\delta W+\delta Q=-PdV+TdS$$

If the mechanical action is reversible, then $\delta W=-PdV$ and thus $\delta Q=TdS$.

It is not the case for the free expansion that is the most radical and simplest example of an irreversible mechanical action: it drives the system violently out of equilibrium.

I'm explaining briefly why $\delta Q=TdS$ holds even in the case of irreversible heat exchange (as long as the work is reversible). For simplicity, we imagine there is no work, the volume is constant and the system undergoes pure heat exchange: the system is inside a heat bath at temperature $T_B$. Heat exchange is reversible when $T_B=T$ and irreversible when $T_B\neq T$.

[image]

When the exchange is irreversible ($T_B\neq T$), even a small heat exchange $\delta Q$ drives the system out of equilibrium. It is easy to imagine a temperature gradient appears inside the system because of the temperature difference. Soon, this gradient will cause turbulences and a complex equilibrium recovery process involving heat conduction and (gaseous) friction (if the system is a gas).

But during a quasistatic infinitesimal heat exchange, the system is initially in an equilibrium state $(V,U)$ and finally in an equilibrium state $(V,U+dU)$ with $dU=\delta Q$. The equality $\delta Q=TdS$ still holds between the initial and final equilibriums. This is because $S$ is a state function and its variation only depends on the initial and final states:

- Initial state: $(V,U)$
- Final state : $(V,U+dU)$

Calculus tells us that the variation of $S$ between these two states is:

$$dS=\left(\frac{dS}{dU}\right)_V dU$$

You can see from the fundamental equation $dU=TdS-PdV$ that $\left(\frac{dS}{dU}\right)_V=\frac{1}{T}$. According to statistical mechanics, this is actually the definition of temperature. Finally, we get:

$$dS=\frac{1}{T} dU=\frac{1}{T} \delta Q$$

We can see that the entropy change of the system depends only on its internal temperature $T$ and the quantity of heat $\delta Q$ being exchanged, but not on the temperature $T_B$ of the environment.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145444/discussion-on-answer-by-benoit-why-isnt-entropy-change-in-free-expansion-0); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.